# UIView autolayout: hierarchy of subviews VS minimum views hierarchy?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout

I'm wondering which is the better way to implement a view which is designed to have complicated subview hierarchy, say a view with one sub view on left and one sub view on right, the left subview has X number of sub-subviews in one column, the right subview has Y number of sub-subviews in a row.
(X and Y varies)

Two ways to implement it:

1. Custom left and right views (ie. UIView subclass), custom left sub-subview, custom right sub-subviews, the root view only deals with custom left and right views, and they configure their sub-subviews
2. Only one view with a column of views (ie left view's sub-subview) on left and a row of views (ie right view's sub-subview) on right

First approach:
pros:

1. clean hierarchy means better maintainability.
2. responsibilities distributed over subviews, so less complication in each view

cons:

1. nested subviews hierarchy
2. *may* have worse performance due to auto-layout
3. delegation chain is more difficult, consider each subview as a button which need to perform certain action, the custom view need to delegate the action all the way back to root view

Second approach:
pros:

1. less subviews
2. *may* have better performance
3. easy delegation chain compared to 1st approach

cons:

1. hard to maintain / modify, as all subviews are in one level, especially with auto-layout
2. messy code base since all views are in one base view

Looks like 1st approach is better, but it still has several cons, is there a completely new way to implement it which copes with all the cons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both subviews (left column and right column) must have something in common, otherwise you would not be showing them at the same time. Because they have a general relation I would have no issue going with option 2. With that said, I would still prefer option 1 for the following reasons:

- A clean hierarchy is easier to understand and maintain.
- View logic that is distributed is easier to understand and will keep your classes smaller (which also means it will be easier to reuse sub views elsewhere).
- "*May* have worse performance" is a big **MAYBE**. You should take actual measurements with Instruments or by using `NSDate` and `timeIntervalSinceNow`. As long as the constraints are always installed at the [nearest common ancestor](http://pilky.me/view/36) you should be fine.
- Delegation and target/action won't be so bad `self.firstView.subView.button.target = self`.

Acceptable performance on all supported hardware should be the primary deciding factor. Maintainability should be a close second.

Go with the first approach.